# Unable to get response from a command (using JSch)

Tags: java, android, jsch

I'm trying to get a response from a command sent through ssh. I connect using JSch lib. Connection is estabilished but getting no response back from the command sent.

```
public void openSSH(
        String username,
        String password,
        String hostname,
        int port) throws Exception {     

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
    this.session = session;
    session.setPassword(password);

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);
    session.connect();

}

public String runCommand(String command)  throws Exception {
    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");      
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = channelssh.getInputStream();
    channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand(command);
    channelssh.connect();        



     System.out.println("Unix system connected...");
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true){

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                Log.v("running", "line");  // won't work
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) {

                    break;
                }
                String line = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                System.out.println("Unix system console output: " +line);
                        channelssh.disconnect();
            }
        }
}



private class AsyncTaskOne extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            openSSH("login", "pass", "10.10.10.80", 22 );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {

        if (value)  {
        try {
            runCommand("ls -llh");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your inputStream is available actually.From my understanding the problem is that your inputStream doesn;t give you anything so instead of

```
 InputStream in = channelssh.getInputStream();
// channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);
```

comment this line and see if there is actually something here.
Also how are you sure that you are connected?
The right way to set the command is this so  please do this:

```
 Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
  ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
```